# Making a view always fit the screen but extend it if the content overflows

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app, where I got a ScrollView and in it another view (a ViewPager). I want the inner View to always be at least big enough to fill the screen, but be scrollable if the content needs more space. So far I haven't found a good solution - `wrap_content` does not fill the screen if the content doesn't uses all the space, and `match_parent` would either not allow scrolling, or, even worse, not work at all because the ScrollView has of course its height set to `wrap_content`.

Any solutions, if using XML or code really appreciated!

Comment: android:fillViewport="true"   this will make the scroll view cover full screen even if the content is not full screen.

Comment: @SaurabhKataria But I need the inner View to fit... And at least with that one it doesn't work.

Comment: You can use a scroll view inside the View pager fragments as the root view and set fiilViewport="true", i think this will solve you problem.

Comment: @SaurabhKataria Wouldn't that be really bad practise? "Never put a scrollable View inside another scrollable view" and stuff...

Comment: So you can use nestedscrollView inside a ScrollView. And yes this wont be a good practise i think, but if the requirement is there then nestedScrollView can help.

Comment: http://ivankocijan.xyz/android-nestedscrollview/  this might help you